# Probability of subsets with different constraints

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $U = \{1, 2, \dots, 1000\}$. We pick a subset from U uniformly at random. That is, every subset has an equal chance of showing up.

1. What is the probability that the empty set is chosen?
2. What is the probability that the subset has at most ten elements?
3. What is the probability that the subset contains the numbers 500 or 1000?
4. What is the probability that the subset does not contain all the multiples of 10?
5. What is the probability that the size of the subset is odd?

My solution:

The total number of subsets of a set with size $n$ is $2^n$

1. $\frac{1}{2^{1000}}$ (only one possibility)
2. $\frac{\dbinom{1000}{10} + \dbinom{1000}{9} + \dots + \dbinom{1000}{1} + \dbinom{1000}{0}}{2^{1000}}$
3. $(1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}})$ (my understanding, if we want the subset to contain a particular number is the same as $1$ minus probability of the subset does not contain a number and itself is equal to a subset of a set of size $1000-1$)
4. $\frac{2^{1000-100}}{2^{1000}} = \frac{2^{900}}{2^{1000}}$ (similar to above. there are 100 multiple of $10$ in $1000$)
5. $\frac{\dbinom{1000}{999} + \dbinom{1000}{997} + \dots + \dbinom{1000}{1}}{2^{1000}}$

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2 - OK.

3. $(1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}})  = (1 - \frac12)  + ( 1 -\frac12) = 1$, but the answer in obviously less than $1$. So no all is good in 4.

In 5 all is OK but there's a closed form.

We know that $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \dbinom{1000}{k}x^k$. Put $x=\pm 1$ and $n=1000$. We got
$$ (1+1)^{1000} = \dbinom{1000}{0} + \dbinom{1000}{1} + \dbinom{1000}{2} + \dbinom{1000}{3} + \dbinom{1000}{4} + \ldots$$
$$ (1 + (-1))^{1000} = \dbinom{1000}{0} - \dbinom{1000}{1} + \dbinom{1000}{2} -\dbinom{1000}{3} + \dbinom{1000}{4} + \ldots$$
Hence $\frac{(1+1)^{1000}  -  (1 + (-1))^{100} }2 = \dbinom{1000}{1} + \dbinom{1000}{3} + \dots + \dbinom{1000}{999}$ and
$$\frac{\dbinom{1000}{999} + \dbinom{1000}{997} + \dots + \dbinom{1000}{1}}{2^{1000}} = \frac12$$

Comment: Where did you find $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{1000} \dbinom{1000}{k}x^k$

Comment: @Node.JS It's binomial theorem in case $n = 1000$. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem