# Probability of subsets with different constraints - follow up

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

This is a [follow-up to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617970/probability-of-subsets-with-different-constraints/4618278#4618278).

Let $U = \{1, 2, \dots, 1000\}$. We pick a subset from U uniformly at random. That is, every subset has an equal chance of showing up.

3. What is the probability that the subset contains the numbers 500 or 1000?
4. What is the probability that the subset does not contain all the multiples of 10?

My original solution:

> The total number of subsets of a set with size $n$ is $2^n$
>
> 3. $(1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}})$ (my understanding, if we want the subset
>    to contain a particular number is the same as $1$ minus probability of
>    the subset does not contain a number and itself is equal to a subset
>    of a set of size $1000-1$)
> 4. $\frac{2^{1000-100}}{2^{1000}} = \frac{2^{900}}{2^{1000}}$ (similar to above. there are 100 multiple of $10$ in $1000$)

But in this is what I was told in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4618278/49780) so it means my original solution wasn't correct:

> $(1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{2^{1000-1}}{2^{1000}})
> > = (1 - \frac12)  + ( 1 -\frac12) = 1$, but the answer in obviously less than $1$. So no all is good in 4.

So I revised my answer and used [binomial statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement) as was recommended in the answer to the original question:

3. $(1 - \frac{\dbinom{999}{0} + \dbinom{999}{1} + \dots + \dbinom{999}{999}}{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{\dbinom{999}{0} + \dbinom{999}{1} + \dots + \dbinom{999}{999}}{2^{1000}}) = (1 - \frac{\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=999}\dbinom{999}{k} }{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=999}\dbinom{999}{k} }{2^{1000}}) = (1 - \frac{(1+1)^{999} }{2^{1000}}) + (1 - \frac{(1+1)^{999} }{2^{1000}}) = (1 - \frac{1 }{2}) + (1 - \frac{1 }{2}) = \frac{1}{2} + = \frac{1}{2} = 1$
4. $\frac{\dbinom{900}{0} + \dbinom{999}{1} + \dots + \dbinom{900}{990}}{2^{1000}} = \frac{\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=900}\dbinom{900}{k} }{2^{1000}} = \frac{(1+1)^{900} }{2^{1000}} = \frac{2^{900} }{2^{1000}}  \frac{1 }{2^{100}}$

And I am getting the same answer. Am I on the right track? I am very confused.

Comment: Not following your computations. How many subsets are there in total?  How many of them contain neither $500$ nor $1000$?  How many of them contain all the multiples of $10$?

Comment: @lulu did you have a chance to read my answers?

Comment: Your answers look overly complicated.  In both cases, you can just read off the desired results with very little computing.  The binomial computations specifically seem unnecessary.

Comment: For the first one (your $\#3$), for instance:  There are $2^{1000}$ subsets in all, and $2^{998}$ that miss both $500,1000$.  hence the probability that you miss both is $\frac 14$ so the probability that you get at least one is $\frac 34$.  The other one is no harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are not on the right track. The first line of your computation is $3(1-1/2)+(1-1/2)=2$ since $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}=2^n$. Since $2$ cannot be a probability, you have not computed a probability.

How many sets are there that contain 500 or 1000? There are $2^{1000}$ in total. For sets containing $500$, we have to include $500$, for any other element we can freely choose if we want to include it or not. This gives $2^{999}$, which also holds for sets containing $1000$. Using inclusion-exclusion, we also need the sets containing both numbers, and a similar reasoning yields $2^{998}$. Thus, the answer to the first (third) question is $(2\cdot 2^{999}-2^{998})/2^{1000}$.

There are $100$ multiples of $20$ in $U$, so using the reasoning above there are $2^{900}$ sets that include all of them. So the probability for a set that does not include all of them is $(2^{1000}-2^{900})/2^{1000}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But my question is also the probability of what exactly did I find? why my answer was wrong